# Red Ale didn't turn out how I thought it would

Tags: recipe, recipe-formulation, extract-brewing

So I followed a recipe called "hoppy red ale" and I just took a sample after 14 days in the fermenter. I'm a little disappointed that it's not as red as I thought it would be. It's more of a brown / golden yellow. My second confusion is the fact that it tastes very similar to my first recipe, although slightly darker / roasted. So looking at these recipes, why didn't the second one turn out as red and why does it taste so much like the first one?

**First recipe (Pale Ale)**

- 1/2lb crystal 20l
- 1/2lb American 2-row
- 5.5lbs DME
- 2oz Centennial hops
- 2oz Cascade hops
- US05

**Second recipe (Hoppy Red Ale)**

- 1lb CaraVienna 35
- 1/2lb Crystal 55
- 1/8lb Roastbar 500
- 6lbs DME
- 2oz Centennial hops
- 1oz Amarillo hops
- 1oz Amarillo hops (dry hopped)
- Imperial A07